# Converting a Plain Text List to an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Using PHP, what would be the best way to convert a Plain Text List to an Associative Array.

The Plain Text List stucture looks like this:

```
Item 1
Item 1 > Sub Item 1.1
Item 1 > Sub Item 1.2
Item 2 
Item 2 > Sub Item 2.1 > Sub Sub Item 2.1.1
Item 2 > Sub Item 2.1 > Sub Sub Item 2.1.2
Item 2 > Sub Item 2.1 > Sub Sub Item 2.1.2 > Sub Sub Sub Item 2.1.2.1
Item 2 > Sub Item 2.2 > Sub Sub Item 2.2.1
Item 2 > Sub Item 2.2 > Sub Sub Item 2.2.2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 4 > Sub Item 4.1
```

The function / method would not be limited to a specific depth.

The desired array would look something like this:

```
$array['Item 1']['Sub Item 1.1'];
$array['Item 1']['Sub Item 1.2'];
$array['Item 2']['Sub Item 2.1'];
$array['Item 2']['Sub Item 2.1']['Sub Sub Item 2.1.1'];
$array['Item 2']['Sub Item 2.1']['Sub Sub Item 2.1.2'];
$array['Item 2']['Sub Item 2.1']['Sub Sub Item 2.1.2']['Sub Sub Sub Item 2.1.2.1'];
$array['Item 2']['Sub Item 2.2']['Sub Sub Item 2.2.1'];
$array['Item 2']['Sub Item 2.2']['Sub Sub Item 2.2.2'];
$array['Item 3'];
$array['Item 4'];
$array['Item 4']['Sub Item 4.1'];
```

Im not sure if this is the best array stucture to adopt.

On the UI Side...

The array will be used to populate a series of heirachal drop down lists through jQuery.ajax, 
where the contents of the child list is dependant on the parent selection.

User selects Item 2, a new list appears with the Sub Items, 
if they select Sub Sub Item 2.1.2 for instance, then a third
list appears with Sub Sub Sub Item 2.1.2.1 as it's only option.

I can do all the jQuery stuff, its just the PHP function that is causing me a headache !

I included an explanation of what I wated to do with the array incase it influences the way the function(s) is(are) written.

Comment: I think i need to rework this idea. The array output isnt going lend itself to what i need to do with it. I appreciate your time and brain power... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `explode`, reference assigning and `array_shift`:

```
$input = "Item 1
Item 1 > Sub Item 1.1
...
Item 4 > Sub Item 4.1";

$lines = explode("\n", $input);
$out = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(" > ", $line);
    $ref = &$out;
    while (count($parts) > 0) {
        if (isset($ref[$parts[0]]) === false) {
            $ref[$parts[0]] = array();
        }
        $ref = &$ref[$parts[0]];
        array_shift($parts);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);
```

Seems to give the correct output.

Comment: What is complex about this? `$ref` walks the path you get from `explode($line)`. I suppose you could write a recursive function instead but as you can see this works just as well.

Comment: this works fine, however i think i need to re-think my original idea, i think an array of the structure i set out will not work for what i want.